# conditionally set or clear bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I came across a code [original link of code](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ConditionalSetOrClearBitsWithoutBranching), in which part of it, is not clear to me.

```
bool f;         // conditional flag
unsigned int m; // the bit mask
unsigned int w; // the word to modify:  if (f) w |= m; else w &= ~m; 
w ^= (-f ^ w) & m;
// OR, for superscalar CPUs:
w = (w & ~m) | (-f & m);
```

Now, In line `w ^= (-f ^ w) & m;` and in line `w = (w & ~m) | (-f & m);` they have used `-f`.  When I tried without `-f` and just used `f` it gave me the same answer. Even when I tried to print `-f` after initializing value of `f=true/false`, its stays some  and does not change. Could someone please tell me what is the significance of `-f` here.

Comment: `w` is initialized when this statement is executed: `w ^= (-f ^ w) & m;`

Comment: source for those wondering https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ConditionalSetOrClearBitsWithoutBranching , you should always add the source and give credits to the original author .

Comment: Of course that is why I wrote I came across a code. Still, you are right, thank you.

Comment: Assuming `f` is an int with value 0 or 1, it works either by the if-else or the single expression (hint: `-f` is either `0000` or `1111`). I haven't tried the superscalar expression. It's rather convoluted, and I would personally prefer to use the if-else method just for the clarity, but where you need very high performance, the one-liner _might_ be faster. Just beware of premature optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're quoting seem to be making the assumption that `(unsigned int)(-true)` will evaluate to `UINT_MAX`. The C standard makes no such guarantee, the value of `(-true)` could be any value whose binary representations is all 1s, including the value `1`.

It's fixable though, by casting. `-(unsigned int)f` should give you the right answer.

When you set an unsigned value to `-1`, the maximum value + 1 is added, and it thus becomes the maximum value for the type, i.e. the one with all bits set to 1. `-0` is equal to `0` obviously. So in the first expression above the value of `f` is supposed to control whether `(-f ^ w)` evaluates to `~w` or to `w`.

Comment: why you can't just negate the `0` considering that is an unsigned integer ? like `~(unsigned int(0))`

Comment: @user2485710 the needed mappings are `0 => 0` and `1 => ~0`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this description from http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/opers.html#unarypm:

> Unary plus and minus operators ('+' and '-')
>
> In these unary + - expressions
>
> ```
> + expr
> - expr
> ```
>
> the expr operand must be of arithmetic type. The result is the value of the operand after any required integral promotions for the unary plus ('+') operator, or negative of the value of the operand after any required integral promotions for the unary minus ('-') operator. Floating point negation is internally executed using the fneg function.
>
> Note that both '+' and '-' operators also have a binary form.